# How to use facebook connect on mobile web application using the OAuth Dialog

Tags: php, facebook

Now I'm developing a mobile web application using facebook connect, but I am having problems with the OAuth Dialog. I use the following facebook documents for my reference:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#web

I choose to use the OAuth Dialog instead of the Login Button because **mobile browsers do not recognize the FBML** (I use the Blackberry browser on testing). The OAuth Dialog also lets me add a list of permissions within the parameters of scope. But the problem is when I've logged in using the OAuth Dialog, **the parameter $me wasn't recognized** so that the login button still appears and doesn't not change to the logout button.
Here is an example of my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
if ($me) {
  echo "<img src=\"images/logoutFB.gif\">";
} else {
  echo "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes&client_id=".$facebook->getAppId()."&redirect_uri=".urlencode("http://MYURL.COM")."&display=wap\"><img src=\"images/loginFB.gif\"></a>";
}
```

Is the parameter $me can't be used if I use the OAuth Dialog to connects to facebook? 
So how do I know that I am already logged into facebook or not if I use the OAuth Dialog?
Please help if you guys have the solution.

Comment: You didn't bother clicking the help button by the post box to gain information on how to format SO posts?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use [the updated PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)

`getSession()` has been replaced by `getUser()`:

```
require './src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '135669679827333',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

    $user = null;
  }
}
```